# Issue with php outputting Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have an image rotation script I wrote in php that randomly finds images from directories, and outputs Javascript.

I call this file with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="getImage.php?t=home">
</script>
```

This file php file writes:

```
 document.write('<div id="slideshow"><img src="images/work/Rotate.jpg" alt="" class="active" /><img src="images/work/Rotate.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/work/Rotate.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/work/Rotate.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/work/Rotate.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/work/Rotate.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/work/Rotate.jpg" alt="" /></div>');
```

and uses the php header:

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```

to send the file as a Javascript file.

The weird thing is, this works on two different hosting accounts with different companies, but not on a third.

Does anybody have any idea what I might be missing?  I have tried changing the Header content type and tried adding [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/244828/set-mime-type-of-php-generated-javascript-file)

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
AddType application/javascript .js
```

to the .htaccess but it didn't work.

Comment: @icktoofay, That is incorrect.  `application/javascript` is the correct type.

Comment: @Brad: You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.  I changed it to `application/javascript` but that didn't fix it.

I changed my search query and managed to find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227638/how-to-embed-php-script-in-javascript) where it said I had to put the `Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");` line at the top of the php file.  I had it in the middle, but for some reason it works fine on other hosts.

Thanks